# Tell dhclient to not use an interface

Tags: dhclient

I have been reading through `man dhclient` and `man dhclient.conf` and cannot find a way to get it to ignore an interface.  As in, pretend it does not exist.

I do not want to shut any interface down.  I just want dhclient to establish a lease on a specific interface and leave the others alone.

I tried this as a very simple `.conf` file that I hoped would work to get it to stop paying attention to iface2.

```
interface "iface1" {

}

interface "iface2" {
        reject 192.168.0.0/16
        reject 10.0.0.0/8
}
```

The point here is to allow it to engage in default behaviour with iface1, but ignore iface2.

But at this point I am just making stupid guesses -- the manual, as far as I can tell, says *absolutely nothing* about disabling or ignoring interfaces, as if this were something ridiculous or impossible.  However, it seems like a very simple task to me and presumably I have misinterpreted or just plain missed something somewhere.

The above conf (invoked `dhclient -v -d -cf that.conf`) does work to connect to and obtain a lease from iface1, but it then continues endlessly to post DCHPDISCOVER, etc, and failures to due with iface2.  The reason I want this to stop is I want to try and do something unrelated with iface2 and if there are problems, I want to be sure it is not because of dhclient.

Note that specifying the interface on the command line (`dhclient -v -d iface1`) results in identical behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, stupid me.  The solution is to simply leave the inteface unmentioned in the conf file:

```
interface "iface1" {

}
```

It now just gets a lease on iface1 and that's it.

Note again this is *not* the behaviour I get from `dhclient iface1`, in which case it first acquires a lease on iface1 but then continues to keep paying attention to everything else -- although there was no pre-existing `dhclient.conf` anywhere and `/etc/dhcp` was empty.

Comment: Leaving an interface unmentioned doesn't work. From man page `Note well: ISC dhclient only maintains one list of interfaces, which is either
determined  at  startup  from  command line arguments, or otherwise is autodetected.`

Answer (score -1):

If you have `iface1` and `iface2` but only want dhclient to get an IP address etc for `iface1`, then why not just run: `dhclient [other-args] iface1`?

By providing it with one or more interface name(s) on the command-line, it will only use that interface or interfaces.

see `man dhclient` for details.

Comment: As mentioned in the question and my answer this is not the observed the behavior. This is what I *assumed* (and have assumed for a long time, in fact), but I noticed it was not the case when I used a (usb tether) interface that doesn't normally exist ("iface1").  `dhclient -v iface1` (how I normally connect) worked fine, then when I was trying to set up `iface2` as an AP (wlan, which is what I commonly use as a client), I noticed in syslog repeated statements from `dhclient` about the wlan `iface2` I did not want it to use. I shut it down and ran it in the foreground (`-d`) and low and behold,

Comment: that's what it does.   I.e., `dhclient -v -d iface1` does a discover and negotiation with iface1, but then endlessly reports messages about iface2 as well (I presume it has old leases related to this interface wherever).  The only way I could stop this was by specifying a conf (`-cf`) which explicitly refers *only* to iface1.

Comment: sorry, i had stopped reading before your last paragraph. should have read to the end.  I would recommend submitting a bug report because the documentation clearly shows that one or more interfaces can be supplied on the command-line, and there's really no point doing that except to limit which interfaces it works on.

Comment: does it do the same if you clear out your old leases file?

Comment: Yeah, it does seem stupid.

Comment: *"does it do the same if you clear out your old leases file?"* -> No, turns out they are stashed in `/var/lib`.  This still contradicts the man page though, which says something about old leases being used "if the dhcp server is not immediately available" -- yet the first thing it does is negotiate a lease with the dhcp server on iface1.

Comment: at least you have relevant info for your bug report - dhclient ignores interface restriction on command line if an old leases file mentions another interface.